# Does drawRect: automatically check whether something is within the bounds of the CGRect passed to it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, drawrect

I'm wondering whether I need to check if something is within the bounds of the CGRect passed to `drawRect:`, or if `drawRect:` automatically handles that for me.

For example, assume that I have 10 `UIBezierPaths` on the screen. Each curve is in an `NSMutableArray` named `curves`. Every time `drawRect:` is called, it loops through this array and draws the curves it finds there. If the use moves one curve, I find its containing `CGRect` and `call [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:containingRect]`. In my `drawRect:` implementation, do I need to personally check whether each of the `UIBezierPaths` falls within the `CGRect` passed to `drawRect:` (using `CGRectIntersectsRect`), or is that handled automatically?

Comment: What happens if you don't check? Does it work?

Comment: it wont handle automatically.u have to

Comment: Mat - yes, it works. But that could be because it's simply redrawing the entire screen, rather than just the dirty rect passed to drawRect:

Comment: @vijay - that's what I suspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This falls into a class of optimizations you'll have to make yourself if you think it's necessary after profiling.

UIKit isn't that smart unfortunately. Though it would probably be too slow if it was!